# How to make 3D 2D text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, text, 3d

I want to make a 3D looking text that would in fact be 2 2D layers.

Here's what I want to make - I duped the layer 2 times and moved the second layer a little lower, then used Blend, recolored and put the original layer on top:

[image: Example 1]

But here's the culprit:

[image: Example 2]

Is there a way to avoid using the Blend command and fixing the curves myself?

Answer (score 3):

sure, just double click on the Blend Option tool and switch to [Specified Steps] and increase the steps the way you don't feel the curves anymore

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Apply a 3D Extrude to your text with options like the following:

[image: 3D Extrude Options]

The 1° rotation along the X axis should be insignificant enough that there will not be any noticeable distortion on the text. You'll end up with something like this:

[image: Extruded text example]

You can then use <kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd> to allow you to manipulate the shapes to recolor, combine shapes, or whatever it is you need.

[image: Illustrator screenshot of finished product]